# I have booked flights tickets for 3 and got one confirmation number, so what should I do to get seats together for no cost?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, airlines, check-in

I am travelling in US (domestic), and have a one conformation number for 3 passengers, so I want all three of us sit together without paying anything.

Comment: Which airline? Any reason you can’t just check in together?

Comment: In addition to the airline, which fare? Most airlines have different conditions depending on the fare (discount or flexible or whatever the airline calls it).

Comment: If it's you, your spouse and a young child, _many_ (but by no means _all_) people are reasonable and it's likely that you'll find someone willing to swap seats to allow the three of you to sit together if you can't reserve them together. Understand, though, that they person you're trying to swap with may have _paid_ for his seat (on the aisle, or up front) and she may not be willing to give it up for free, so don't be miffed if you don't find someone willing to swap.

Answer (score 6):

Some tickets include free seat selection, others do not. That's a decision you need to make when you buy the ticket.

If your tickets do include free seat selection you can just picks seats online at the airline's website. Even with a single confirmation number, you can select seats for each passenger.

If your ticket does NOT include free seat selection you will have to pay for it.

If you don't have a reserved seat, you can pick one at check in from whatever is left. You can try to check in as early as possible and hope for the best but on most US domestic routes the chances of finding three empty seats next to each other during check in are slim.

Comment: "on most US domestic routes the chances of finding three empty seats next to each other during check in are slim."

This isn't necessarily true. Many US airlines block a row or two of seats for families to either select together at check-in (If their ticket type allows it) or to be assigned together at the gate by the agent.